# Problems filling DataFrames in dict of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have something like a matrix of empty dataframes.

```
A = {'folder1':{'case1':pd.Dataframe(), 'case2':pd.Dataframe(),... , 'case8':pd.Dataframe()}\
    {'folder2':{'case1':pd.Dataframe(), 'case2':pd.Dataframe(),... , 'case8':pd.Dataframe()}\
...
    {'foldern':{'case1':pd.Dataframe(), 'case2':pd.Dataframe(),... , 'case8':pd.Dataframe()}}
```

In which `A[folder][case]` is a empty DataFrame.

I already have another dict of dicts of non-empty dataframes of the form

```
BASIS = {'folder1':{'arch01':pd.Dataframe(...), 'arch02':pd.Dataframe(...)}\
    {'folder2':{'arch01':pd.Dataframe(...), 'arch02':pd.Dataframe(...)}\
...
    {'foldern':{'arch01':pd.Dataframe(...), 'arch02':pd.Dataframe(...)}}
```

In which `BASIS[folder][arch]` is a non-empty dataframe with lots of row I want to separate to others `A[folder]['case']`.

For example, `BASIS[folder]['arch01']` is going to be devided into `A[folder]['case1']` + `A[folder]['case2']` + `A[folder]['case3']`

Basically I want to devide `[arch]` in `['casei']`, `['casej']` where 'i' and 'j' are the cases where some conditions happen

I'm trying to give values to these dataframe this way:

```
for folder in ['folder1', 'folder2',... 'foldern']:
    
    IRLB = BASIS[folder]["arch01"].copy()
    condition01 = IRLB.loc[(IRLB['Column3'].str.contains('AAA',case=False))]
    A[folder]['case1'] = A[folder]['case1'].append(condition01)
    
    condition02 = IRLB.loc[(IRLB['Column3'].str.contains('BBB',case=False))]
    A[folder]['case2'] = A[folder]['case2'].append(condition02)        
    ... (and other conditions to others cases of A)
```

I'm getting the following error:
**Only the last folder of A is being filled**, the other ones still empty dataframes.

Comment: I've already tried A[folder]['case1'] = condition01
What happens is that the last A[folder] contains only condition01 for the last foder. When I use the code above, A[folder] contains also condition01 for all previous folder

Comment: I think you might be better served with a single dataframe that also contains columns that indication which folder and case is associated with each row

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake. Sorry for everyone who lost time reading it.
The problem was:
Since my language is portuguese, sometimes I iterate the Folders in portuguese, as "pasta",
I was iterating "folder" and using "pasta"
As my last value of pasta was relative to the last folder (pasta = 'foldern' outside the loop), I was using always the last folder, not the iterating folder ('folder1', 'folder2', n...). Hope this post helps anybody
Thanks